# Java8 with Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, java-8, appium

I am new to `Java-8` and appium and trying to write my webdriver code in `Java-8` as mentioned below

Currently below code is working fine but I don't want to write Function and Consumer in separate lines as mentioned below in lines line 5 and line 6 and i want to optimize the code more i.e something like Function within Consumer or Consumer within Function.Thanks! in Advance

```
public class Gestures_Drag_And_Drop {

     AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver;

     Function<String, AndroidElement> F = driver::findElementByXPath;//line 5
     Consumer<AndroidElement> C = AndroidElement::click;  //line 6

     Gestures_Drag_And_Drop() {
         C.accept(F.apply("//android.widget.TextView[@text='Views']"));
     }

     public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
         new Gestures_Drag_And_Drop();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function or consumer variable not need to be just method reference, you can define whatever method body you want using lambda expressions. I guess you asking for something like this:

```
BiConsumer<String, WebDriver> findAndClick = (locator, webdriver) -> webdriver.findElement(By.xpath(locator)).click();
```